# Why does Haskell force data constructor's first letter to be upper case?

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming

Give an ugly example:

```
data Bighead = Big

little = 1 

f1 = little :: Int

f2 = Big :: BigHead
```

In my opinion:

`f1` and `f2` all point to some data. the only different of (`little` and `Big`) is
little has a piece of code to do evaluation. but Big doesn't.

They all have a rewritable body, little can be transformed from a collection of data to a result, and Big is just don't do the last step --- it always holds this data forms (but recursively they can be evaluated).

But in syntax form, they are almost the same: can be applied, can be evaluated.

One big deal may be that functions can't alter its applied params, but data can do.

Is this the only reason that Haskell treats data and function's names differently?

Call for analysis :-)

**edit: some more pads**

```
data A = B Int
```

type of `B`:

```
B :: Int -> A

b :: Int -> A

b = B
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [Haskell 98 Language](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/) we see the core distinction in identifier tokens in Haskell:

```
varid   ->   (small {small | large | digit | ' })<reservedid>
conid   ->   large {small | large | digit | ' }
```

That is, the language fundamentally distinguish *variable names* ("varid") from *constructor names* ("conid"), at all levels of the language (both value and type variables and constructors). So clearly, Haskell distinguishes identifiers into two main namespaces (well, there are others, if you count modules and classes), but two primary ones,  those that begin with a lower-case letter (variable identifiers) and those that begin with an upper-case letter (constructor identifiers).

So, given that we *do* distinguish constructors from variables, the question is "why?".

*Reading types*

One plausible argument is that it makes it very easy to spot *parameters* in types (e.g. polymorphic types).

*Pattern matching*

Secondly, and more importantly, we have uniform syntax for data construction and deconstruction (pattern matching). Whenever you see an upper case identifier in a pattern,

```
case x of
   Foo y z -> ...
```

You *know* that `Foo` is a data structure being taken apart and its components named. Correspondingly, whenever you see an upper case identifier in an expression,

```
g (f (Foo 1 2)
```

you *know* that `f` is receiving a newly built `Foo` data type with two arguments.

So, since constructors (both type and value) are so important in the language, this simple restriction to upper case identifiers makes it much easier for a human to see what is going on in a piece of code. In some ways upper case letters make up for the lack of other syntactic noise in the language, as an aid to the reader.

---

*Namespaces*

> There are six kinds of names in Haskell : those for variables and constructors denote values; those for type variables, type constructors, and type classes refer to entities related to the type system; and module names refer to modules. There are two constraints on naming:
>
> Names for variables and type variables are identifiers beginning with lowercase letters or underscore; the other four kinds of names are identifiers beginning with uppercase letters.
> An identifier must not be used as the name of a type constructor and a class in the same scope.
> These are the only constraints; for example, Int may simultaneously be the name of a module, class, and constructor within a single scope.

*Haskell B*

In Haskell B, constructors and variables could use either case.

Comment: As top-level architecture has too few different things, so make this limitation can help human's limited brain-functions works better? like other syntactic-sugars. :)

Comment: A very good argument was given by Kevin Hammond in support of this, that in ML, constructors *may* be lower case, which leads to scary errors if you remove a constructor from a data type, and a variable with the same name happens to be in scope... https://twitter.com/#!/khstandrews/status/77431658399281152

Comment: great, that really matters! So know we have strong reason for distinguish Cons/name

Comment: @DonStewart: The error is actually not that scary.  At least PolyML, which in my opinion reports the best error messages among all ML implementations, just says the removed identifier (suppose some cases of some functions still cover it) is not a constructor, which I think quite accurate.

Comment: "make up for the lack of other syntactic noise" - if it was truly "noise", why make up for it?

Comment: Seriously, what's Haskell B?

Answer (score 12):

Constructor names need to be syntactically different from variable/function names to differentiate between variables and constructors in pattern matches. Example:

```
f (Foo bar) Baz bay = bar + bay
```

Here Haskell knows that `Foo` and `Baz` are constructors it should match against and `bar` and `bay` are variables it should introduce because of the way they are capitalized.

Comment: This isn't really an issue in the `Foo` case, because the parentheses would disambiguate even if there were no upper/lowercase distinction. The real issue is in the difference between `Bar`, a constructor to compare the second argument of `f` to, and `bay`, a local name for the third argument to `f`.

Comment: @amalloy We could still look up scope for `baz`, and if we've found it, we could think this is a pattern match. The _real_ issue is that in such case we'd get silently changed semantics of a function if the constructor `baz` was (un)defined. So the whole point in case distinction is to disallow non-local silent changes in semantics.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to disambiguating parsing etc., already mentioned, there's
also readability (and parsing) for humans reading the program.  Some
supporting quotes:

> Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.

--- Abelman and Sussman, *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.

--- Martin Fowler

Comment: Now if you had just explained how readability was connected to the capitalization. Capitalization in programming styles is probably one of the most-subjective aspects. It must be the deconstruction-problem.